# Chrome renders Facebook wrong

Tags: linux-mint, chrome

Just installed Chrome  on Linux Mint. Total moron: thought I was updating Chromium, turns out they're not the same thing, duh. Whatever, got it working may as well try it.

Anyway, it does strange things with Facebook. In a maximized window it displays the page in maybe the middle 70% of the width of the window, with 15% blank space on either side.

(Yes, other sites are fine. And yes, FB is fine in another browser.)

I can't imagine this is actually on-topic here, but you do have that @chrome tag...

Comment: An image here wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not much different to what I can see in my Firefox. That's how this page is built. You can zoom in and out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.